# Is product of locally compact spaces always locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Suppose we have $X_1, \dots , X_n$ be locally compact topological spaces. We can Show that
$X_1 \times \dots \times X_n$ is locally compact. By taking product of respective Compact sets which containing the ngbhd of the point.

I was wondering what will happen if I take arbitrary product. It feels like same proof works.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not work, because, in general, a product of neighborhoods is not a neighborhood (because, in general, a product of open sets is not an open set).

Actually, given a family of locally compact spaces, their Cartesian product is locally compact (with respect to the product topology) if and only if only finitely many of them are not compact.

Comment: Can you expline the statement" iff only finitely many of them are not compact"?,I don't know where do we need this in proof.

Comment: yes.But, I was thinking what will happen if I take infinite product.

Comment: Yes, we do. Suppose that $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M_\lambda$ is locally compact. Take an element $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}M_\lambda$. Then it has a compact neighborhood $K$. Since it is a neighborhood of $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$, it must contain a set of the form $\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$, where each $A_\lambda$ is an open subset of $M_\lambda$ and, for all but finitely many $\lambda$'s, $A_\lambda=M_\lambda$. But then, if $\lambda$ is not among those finitely many indexes, $\pi_\lambda(K)=M_\lambda$, and so $M\lambda$ is compact.